# Special Characters in Snowpipe like ñ and ß

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to upload a csv that has a column with multiple languages, and multiple characters. Once they have been staged, I am not sure of the best way to select or search that column.

Here is an example of the few lines of csv, apologies for the bad formatting, I cannot share the data, but it's likeness is below:

```
+----+--------------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id |  username    |  tweet_id |  tweet_content                                                       |
+----+--------------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 03 |  generationz |  123345   |  "toto je nejlepší zpětná vazba na světě"                            |
| 04 |  generationz |  122334   |  "¿Dónde está el mejor lugar para comer? estoy realmente hambriento" |
+----+--------------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If this data will be searched on this column, what is the best transformation or indexing that can be done with the special characters?

Comment: I don't really understand - when someone does a search on this column won't they be inputting the characters in the same format as they are represented in the database? if you change an š to an s it isn't the same thing anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple ideas: Use TRANSLATE() to efficiently replace or eliminate unwanted chars.  Better yet, configure table COLLATION for accent-insensitive comparisons.